# shell script to execute multiple informatica work flows

Tags: shell, solaris, informatica

I am relatively new to shell scripting and UNIX. I am using a Solaris box and the problem is that
we have a shell script called `strtwrfl.sh` which takes a parameter as the workflow name and starts the workflow, e.g. `./strtwrfl.sh ABC` where `ABC` is the workflow name.

I have to run over 200 of such workflows, each workflow is dependent on the successful completion of the previous workflow, i.e. if there are 2 workflows `ABC` and `BCD`, `strtwrfl.sh BCD` will be successful only if `strtwrfl.sh ABC` successfully executed.

Each workflow takes different time to execute successfully.

I have to write a single shell script such that those 200+ informatica workflows must (I dont mind manually entering those workflows into the script) execute one after another, and if one fails the script should halt displaying which workflow failed.

Since this is a production environment I will not be able to share `strtwrfl.sh` here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure I understand your question correctly, but if all you want to do is call a script numerous times in a row with a different parameter and die if an execution fails, you can do something like this:

`meta_strtwrfl.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

script="./strtwrt.sh"
workflows="
        ABC
        BCD
        CDE
"

for workflow in ${workflows}; do
        "${script}" "${workflow}" || { echo "$0: workflow '${workflow}' failed!"; exit 1; }
done
echo "$0: all workflows finished successfully!"
```

Change `script="./strtwrt.sh"` to reflect the path to your `strtwrt.sh` script and change `workflows` accordingly. I don't know which standard shell you have on your solaris system, so we don't use an array for the `workflow` variable, which means that your workflow names cannot have spaces in them this way.

Example runs:

```
$ ./meta_strtwrfl.sh
./meta_strtwrfl.sh: all workflows finished successfully!

$ ./meta_strtwrfl.sh
./meta_strtwrfl.sh: workflow 'ABC' failed!
```

Comment: Hi Buddy thank you ... this code seams to work fine , but it will not wait till all tasks in workflows are executed .. i had tried something similar. 
I found another interesting script in the informatica directory itself which is runmaps.sh which address my problem ..
It takes a .dat file as a parameter where we list all the workflows.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "will not wait till all tasks in workflows are executed" - your workflow scripts are started sequentially. But if you have a (different) solution to your problem, you can add and accept your own answer, so this question does not remain floating around unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt this be really straightforward ... enter each of these entries on one row.. one after other..

./strtwrfl.sh ABC
./strtwrfl.sh ABC1
./strtwrfl.sh ABC2
..
..
..

and so on..

That would be bare bones..

You can then improvise this by putting in error handling..

or do you want to achieve something different ? which I am not able to catch from the question description ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<<'notrequired'               
            wfrunid=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -usd ${USD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} ${workflow_name} | grep "Workflow run id" | awk -F"[" '{print $2}' | awk -F"]" '{print $1}'`
                        cur_wf_status=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -usd ${USD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} ${workflow_name} | grep "Workflow run status" | awk -F"[" '{print $2}' | awk -F"]" '{print $1}'`

                        if [ "${cur_wf_status}" == "Suspended" ] 
                            then
                                echo "Workflow $workflow_name  Status :${cur_wf_status}"  
                                echo "Workflow $workflow_name Runid :${wfrunid}"  
                                echo "                                              " 
                                echo "######################################## Running workflow in Re-START mode start ################################" 
                                echo "#################################################################################################################" 
                                echo "#################################################################################################################" 


                                pmcmd recoverworkflow -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -usd ${USD} -f ${folder_name} -paramfile ${param_file} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} -wfrunid ${wfrunid} ${workflow_name} 

                                if [ $?  -ne  0 ]
                                    then 
                                           echo "################################################# END OF LOG ####################################################" 
                                           exit 1
                                fi                                          
                                while (true)
                                    do
                                        rec_wf_status=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -usd ${USD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} ${workflow_name} | grep "Workflow run status" | awk -F"[" '{print $2}' | awk -F"]" '{print $1}'`

                                        rec_wf_log_name=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -usd ${USD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE}  ${workflow_name} | grep "Workflow log file" | awk -F"[" '{print $2}' | awk -F"]" '{print $1}'`

                                        case "${rec_wf_status}" in
                                        ("Suspended"|"Failed"|"Aborted"|"Stopped") sleep 10

                                        rec_wf_error_start=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -usd ${USD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE}  ${workflow_name} | sed -n '/Workflow run error message: /=' | sed -n '$p' 2> /dev/null`

                                        rec_w_error_end=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -usd ${USD} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} ${workflow_name} | sed -n '/Start time: /=' | sed -n '$p' 2> /dev/null`

                                        rec_wf_error_end=`expr $rec_w_error_end - 1 2>/dev/null`

                                        rec_wf_error=`pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -usd ${USD} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} ${workflow_name} | sed -n "$rec_wf_error_start,$rec_wf_error_end p" 2> /dev/null`





                        rec_task_name=`echo ${wf_error} | sed 's/\(^.*task instance\)\(.*\)\(].*$\)/\2/' | awk -F"[" '{print $2}' | awk -F"]" '{print $1}'`

                                        rec_task_type=`pmcmd gettaskdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -usd ${USD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} -w ${workflow_name} ${rec_task_name} | grep "Task type:" | awk -F"[" '{print $2}' | awk -F"]" '{print $1}'`

                                        rec_task_error_start=`pmcmd gettaskdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -usd ${USD} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} -w ${workflow_name} ${rec_task_name} | sed -n '/Task run error message: /=' | sed -n '$p' 2>/dev/null` 

                                        rec_error_end=`pmcmd gettaskdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -usd ${USD} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} -w ${workflow_name} ${rec_task_name} | sed -n '/Integration Service: /=' | sed -n '$p' 2>/dev/null`

                                        rec_task_error_end=`expr $rec_error_end - 1 2> /dev/null`

                                        rec_task_error=`pmcmd gettaskdetails -sv ${INTEG_SERVICE} -d ${DOMAIN} -usd ${USD} -u ${USER_NAME} -p ${PASSWORD} -f ${folder_name} -rin ${RUN_INSTANCE} -w ${workflow_name} ${rec_task_name} | sed -n "${rec_task_error_start},${rec_task_error_end} p" 2> /dev/null`

                                        print_error=`echo "Task ${rec_task_name} Failed"`

                                        case "${rec_task_type}" in
                                          ("Session") print_error=`echo "${rec_task_name} ${rec_task_error}"`
                                          esac
                                         esac 

                                        case "$rec_wf_status" in 
                                        "Suspended") echo "                     " 
                                               echo "Workflow Status  : ${rec_wf_status}"  
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################ WORKFLOW ERROR #################################################" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "WORKFLOW ${rec_wf_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# TASK ERROR ####################################################" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "Task Type: ${rec_task_type}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "${print_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               execution_stop_time=`date "+%d-%m-%Y-%T"`
                                               echo "Execution Stop Time : $execution_stop_time" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# END OF LOG ####################################################" 
                                               exit 1
                                               ;;
                                        "Succeeded") echo "                     " 
                                               echo "Workflow Status  : ${rec_wf_status}"  
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "Workflow Run Successfully Completed"  
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               execution_stop_time=`date "+%d-%m-%Y-%T"`
                                               echo "Execution Stop Time : $execution_stop_time" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# END OF LOG ####################################################" 
                                               exit 0
                                               ;;
                                        "Aborted") echo "                     "   
                                               echo "Workflow Status  : ${rec_wf_status}"  
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################ WORKFLOW ERROR #################################################" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "WORKFLOW ${rec_wf_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# TASK ERROR ####################################################" 
                                               echo "Task Type: ${rec_task_type}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "${print_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               execution_stop_time=`date "+%d-%m-%Y-%T"`
                                               echo "Execution Stop Time : $execution_stop_time" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# END OF LOG ####################################################" 
                                               exit 1
                                               ;;
                                        "Failed") echo "                     "  
                                               echo "Workflow Status  : ${rec_wf_status}"  
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################ WORKFLOW ERROR #################################################" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "WORKFLOW ${rec_wf_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# TASK ERROR ####################################################" 
                                               echo "Task Type: ${rec_task_type}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "${print_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               execution_stop_time=`date "+%d-%m-%Y-%T"`
                                               echo "Execution Stop Time : $execution_stop_time" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# END OF LOG ####################################################" 
                                               exit 1
                                               ;;
                                        "Stopped") echo "                     "   
                                               echo "Workflow Status  : ${rec_wf_status}"  
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################ WORKFLOW ERROR #################################################" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "WORKFLOW ${rec_wf_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# TASK ERROR ####################################################" 
                                               echo "Task Type: ${rec_task_type}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "${print_error}" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               execution_stop_time=`date "+%d-%m-%Y-%T"`
                                               echo "Execution Stop Time : $execution_stop_time" 
                                               echo "                     " 
                                               echo "################################################# END OF LOG ####################################################" 
                                               exit 1
                                               ;;          
                                        esac

                                    done    

                        else
notrequired
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.